# Python MySQLdb update table from dictionary of lists

Tags: python, dictionary, mysql-python

I am trying to update a MySQL table through Python, using MySQLdb package.

I would want to update a certain table with data from a dictionary having this format:

```
muts={'YES': [rice,bread,pasta]
       'NO': [sweets,fat,milk,choco]}
```

I need that for rows on the mysql table whose column `food` value corresponding with each of the entries on lists (values for the dictionary above), another column called `accept` would be updated with its corresponding key; 'YES' or 'NO'.

So far, when I wanted to update entries from a table using a single list, I use to do 
the following:

```
food=[sweets,fat,milk,choco]
sql = "UPDATE test2 g SET accept='NO' WHERE g.food IN (%s)"
to_add = ', '.join(list(map(lambda x: '%s', any_list)))
sql = sql % to_add
cursor.execute(sql, any_list)
```

But now that I want to simultaneously update with key-values from a dictionary; I got lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the sql with two %s's and loop through your dictionary for the to_add line, so you place the `k` and the `to_add`:

```
>>> muts={'YES': ['rice','bread','pasta'],
...        'NO': ['sweets', 'fat', 'milk', 'choco']}
>>> muts
{'YES': ['rice', 'bread', 'pasta'], 'NO': ['sweets', 'fat', 'milk', 'choco']}
>>> sql = "UPDATE test2 g SET accept='%s' WHERE g.food IN (%s)"
>>> for k in muts:
...     to_add = ', '.join(muts[k])
...     ex_sql = sql % (k, to_add)
...     print ex_sql
...     # cursor.execute(ex_sql) here
... 
UPDATE test2 g SET accept='YES' WHERE g.food IN (rice, bread, pasta)
UPDATE test2 g SET accept='NO' WHERE g.food IN (sweets, fat, milk, choco)
>>>
```

You can put that in a function and pass it 'any_list'. Unless execute takes a list of statements, you can't use the `.execute( , any_list)` in one line.

Btw, ***the join line should actually be:***

```
to_add = "'%s'" % "', '".join(muts[k])
```

so that you end up with `'` quotes around each food type:

```
... # that gives...
UPDATE test2 g SET accept='YES' WHERE g.food IN ('rice', 'bread', 'pasta')
UPDATE test2 g SET accept='NO' WHERE g.food IN ('sweets', 'fat', 'milk', 'choco')
```

You may also want to use the `?` placeholder syntax instead of `%s` to avoid sql injection attacks.

Comment: Woah, amazing. 
You've just made my day, @aneroid.
Thank u so much!